# How to use AddMenu in Lauterbach while a PRACTICE script loop is running(and blocking) execution?

Tags: scripting, trace32, lauterbach

I have created a PRACTICE Lauterbach script in order retrieve certain strings from buffers, from different situations.

I place 4 breakpoints in the different places where I retrieve the buffers from.

I wanted to retrieve the info in a non-blocking way, as if the it was an interrupt service routine. To this end, I made use of the GLOBALON command, as follows:

```
            GLOBALON PBREAK GOSUB BB_HIT_CALLBACK
```

And inside the BB_HIT_CALLBACK, I inserted the service routines for each of the 4 breakpoints.

```
            BB_HIT_CALLBACK:
                IF (sYmbol.EXIST(BREAK_LABEL1))
                 (
                     IF (REGISTER(pc)==ADDRESS.offset(BREAK_LABEL1))
                     (
                         GOSUB ISR1

                     )
                 )  
                IF (sYmbol.EXIST(BREAK_LABEL2))
                 (
                     IF (REGISTER(pc)==ADDRESS.offset(BREAK_LABEL2))
                     (
                         GOSUB ISR1

                     )
                 )  
                IF (sYmbol.EXIST(BREAK_LABEL3))
                 (
                     IF (REGISTER(pc)==ADDRESS.offset(BREAK_LABEL3))
                     (
                         GOSUB ISR1

                     )
                 )  
                IF (sYmbol.EXIST(BREAK_LABEL4))
                 (
                     IF (REGISTER(pc)==ADDRESS.offset(BREAK_LABEL4))
                     (
                         GOSUB ISR1

                     )
                 )  
            RETURN
```

On the other hand, in the normal execution, I placed a simple infinite loop.

```
                WHILE TRUE()
                (
                    If (!STATE.RUN())
                    (
                      Go
                    )
                )

                ENDDO
```

This mantains the program in a loop, only broken by the GLOBALON PBREAK command. I wish to be able to have a toolbar button to end the execution of this loop, but while running, the script only responds to the breakpoints, and UI elements are being ignored.

How can I stop the execution of the loop, from a UI element?

I have been able to set read the seconds, and timeout at 60 seconds, but that is not good enough for what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `GLOBALON PBREAK` is not the best solution for your problem.

You could use command breakpoints to directly execute any PRACTICE command or script when each breakpoint is hit:

```
Break.Set BREAK_LABEL1 /CMD "DO your_script.cmm ISR1"
Break.Set BREAK_LABEL2 /CMD "DO your_script.cmm ISR2"
Break.Set BREAK_LABEL3 /CMD "DO your_script.cmm ISR3"
Break.Set BREAK_LABEL4 /CMD "DO your_script.cmm ISR4"
```

This is also possible with the `Break.Set` dialog if you click the “advanced” button.

With this setup, `your_script.cmm` could look like this:

```
PRIVATE &arg
ENTRY &arg

IF "&arg"!=""
(
    GOSUB &arg
)
ELSE
(
    // script called without arguments -- maybe set the breakpoints here
)

ENDDO

ISR1:
    PRINT "ISR1 reached!"

    // resume execution of core
    Go.direct
    RETURN

// and so on for ISR2 to ISR4
```

This way, your script would not need to be running at all. You could set up a toolbar button, menu item or even a dialog that starts another script, which in turn stops the core and removes the breakpoints.